# AngularJS 1.6 iteriating through array returns object data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Still new to AngularJS, and I'm trying to format my response data from an array.

As I understand it, it should be a pretty simple concept, you loop through a response.data objectset and access item.properties within the object and it will return the data as a string.

My issue is that it doesn't seem to be returning it as a string, but as an object value(?).

Best illustrated with an example. The data is being pulled from my local solr instance, just fyi.

**Relevant html:** (the loop)

```
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter:philter">
        <span class="item trim"><a href='{{item._name}}' alt='{{item._name}}'>{{item._name}}</a><br />{{item._content}}</span>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('searchBtnCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'PagerService', function ($scope, $http, PagerService) {
    var vm = this;

    $scope.performSearch = function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        $('.item').remove();

        $http.get('http://localhost:8984/solr/index/select?q=_content:' + $scope.searchInput + '&fl=_name,_content,_fullpath&omitHeader=true&rows=10000&wt=json').then(function (response) {
            $scope.responseData = response.data.response.docs;
            vm.resultCount = response.data.response.docs.length;
            vm.itemsToDisplay = $scope.responseData; // array of items to be paged
            vm.pager = {};
            vm.setPage = setPage;

            initController();

            function initController() {
                // initialize to page 1
                vm.setPage(1);
            }

            function setPage(page) {
                if (page < 1 || page > vm.pager.totalPages) {
                    return;
                }

                // get pager object from service
                vm.pager = PagerService.GetPager(vm.itemsToDisplay.length, page);


                // get current page of items
                vm.items = vm.itemsToDisplay.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1);
            }
        });

    }

}]);
```

**Output from console** (pagination returning correct number of objects)

```
Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 3 more… ]
```

Clicking the first object in the array has the following output:

```
_content:Array[1]
_fullPath:/path/to/file
_name:Array[1]
_proto_:Object
```

...and then to expand the _name array:

```
0:"Name of first item"
length:1
```

What i'm expecting is that the div will contain the item name and content in string form.

What I'm getting is the correct data, just encased in [" "].
ex.

**Unexpected results**

```
<div>
   ["P4P Correspondence"]
   ["P4P Correspondence \nPay for Performance (P4P) \nIEHP will keep you informed of past....
```

Is there something else I can do in the expression to get it to strip out the opening and closing brackets/quotes?

thanks!

Comment: What does the JSON look like returned from the GET call on http://localhost:8984/solr/index/select?q=_content:...?

Comment: Let me update my question with that info. :)

Comment: seems like you would need to go deeper into the JSON in your ng-repeat. i.e. {{item._name[0]}} or something like that. If you expand the _name array, what does it look like?

Comment: Can I do that in an expression? I'm not sure how to add a [i] type of variable to the expression. I'll update the question with your new request.

Comment: Wow, that was it.. just adding the [0] did the trick.. You da man Carlo! Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 1):

The better solution will be getting it done on the return of an ajax call:

```
vm.itemsToDisplay = $scope.responseData;
vm.itemsToDisplay = vm.itemsToDisplay.map(function(item,index){
   return item[0];
});
```

This way you will no longer need to add all the "[0]" concat on your html.

Comment: Interesting, I'll play around with this idea. Thanks for the suggestion Yaje. :)

Comment: When I attempt to add this code, I get the following error.  'Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys....  Any thoughts on what I did wrong?

Comment: Hi Nick, i would suggest that you fix your return than manipulating it on your return call. But as for your question, can you comment here what `vm.itemsToDisplay` looks like after the process?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Carlo, the solution was rather simple.

I just needed to dig deeper in my array and add a [0] in my expression.

So the full solution looks like:

```
<span class="item trim"><a href='{{item._name[0]}}' alt='{{item._name[0]}}'>{{item._name[0]}}</a><br />{{item._content[0]}}</span>
```

Thanks Carlo! Worked perfectly. :)